# C# TCP listener

Tags: c#, .net, networking, tcp

I don't want to reinvent the wheel with another TCP server wrapper, so are there any good out of the box open source TCP server wrappers for .NET C#?

Indy C# is kinda dead, and I cannot find any other packages that are atleast a bit maintained..

Comment: `System.Net.Sockets.TcpListener`?  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcplistener.aspx

Comment: Please list any functionality you want from a wrapper that just using the TcpListener wouldn't give you.

Comment: Agree with Matt and Robin... I recently created a small multithreaded server using Tcp* and everything worked great and was very trivial. Are you thinking of some sort of message passing protocol perhaps?

Comment: No I don't care about the protocol. 

If the C# native library is sufficient I will try that, but I was not certain about thread handling, connecting, disconnect etc. There is a vast ammount of tutorials on google, but most of them are very old and all of them use different methods. 

Also OK is a good tutorial which really takes some good methods.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`TcpListener` is a decent blocking/polling TCP server wrapper. There is also [Nito.Async](http://nitoasync.codeplex.com/), which is a threadsafe asynchronous TCP server/client wrapper.